# Numpy array element identification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the a nested array of the following type:

```
array = [[3,a],[3,b],[4,c],[7,d],[3,e]]
```

I would to be able to identify all elements with a given first index and create a new array. For example, for first index 3 I would get: `[a,b,e]`.

Comment: Is `array` a numpy array or a list?  Looks like a list.  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what you need help with. What have you tried and how are you stuck? For tips, check out [ask]. Also, are the letters supposed to be strings? then they need to be quoted.

Comment: If that really is a numpy array, simple indexing works: `arr[arr[:,0]=='3',1]`.  That selects the first column, tests for a value match, and uses the resulting boolean array so seleect values from the other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each nested list has exactly 2 elements, it can be done this way:

```
def create_list(input: list, index: int) -> list:
    result = []
    for i in range(len(input)):
        if input[i][0] == index:
            result.append(input[i][1])
    return result
```